# After "some", plural or singular verb?

Tags: verb-agreement, quantifiers, premodifiers

In these sentences:

> "Some *(composes/compose)* delightful music"
>   "Some of them *(write/writes)* wonderful books"

Which form of the verb should I use?

Answer (score 0):

The subject’s premodifier does not change the grammatical number of that subject for purposes of verb agreement.

Because *poets* is plural, all of these take a plural verb:

- Poets write sonnets.
- Some poets write sonnets.
- Some of the poets write sonnets.
- Most poets write sonnets.
- Most of the poets write sonnets.
- Many poets write sonnets.
- Many of the poets write sonnets.
- Lots of poets write sonnets.
- A lot of poets write sonnets.
- No poets write sonnets.
- None of the poets write sonnets.

But because *rice* is singular, all of these take a singular verb:

- Rice is good for you.
- Some rice is good for you.
- Some of the rice is good for you.
- Most rice is good for you.
- Most of the rice is good for you.
- Much rice is good for you.
- Much of the rice is good for you.
- Lots of rice is good for you.
- A lot of rice is good for you.
- No rice is good for you.
- None of the rice is good for you.

As you see, the premodifier does not affect subject–verb agreement.